# Spring MVC OpenSessionInViewInterceptor Not Working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been racking my brain for awhile on this one. I had temporarily put it aside, but now it's time to pick it up again. The short version is this: although I have the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor configured in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file, I still get the dreaded LazyIntializationException.

Now, for the details.

I have the OSIV interceptor configured in my dispatcher-servlet.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />

<!-- This MUST be defined here or the DispatcherServlet will act a bit funky -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.me.app.web.controller" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<!-- Convenient way to map URLs to JSPs w/o having a Controller -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" view-name="index" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/UserAgreement.html"
    view-name="UserAgreement" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*.html" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

The Hibernate SessionFactory and TransactionManager beans are defined in the regular applicationContext.xml file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* *.manager.*Manager.*(..))" id="serviceOperations"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceOperations" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibername.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.me.app.model" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Using Spring 3.1.1 and Hibernate 4.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jason

EDIT: On suggestion, I attempted to switch to the Filter rather than the Interceptor. I commented out the entire  section of dispatch-servlet.xml and added the following to web.xml (with other filters and filter mappings shown as well):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml
            classpath:security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>osiv</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- This filter checks to see if the user has accepted terms -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>acceptTermsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.me.web.filter.terms.AcceptTermsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>osiv</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>

<filter-name>acceptTermsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>

    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Your dispatcher-servlet.xml defines two bean instances of type OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.  Do you need both?  You could leave the top level one, and reference it in the interceptor definition, or remove the top-level instance and leave the nested one.  I don't know if this is the root cause of the unexpected behavior, but it might help.

Comment: That was a leftover from my attempts to make it work. I took out the extra declaration and it still didn't work. I also edited the example to take out the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the OSIV for expanding out a relation in the jsp view - if this is the case then an interceptor may not work, as interceptors complete their handling before the view is rendered, in this specific case before the jsp is rendered by the container the hibernate session would have been closed.

A better approach may be to use OSIV filter - `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter` which will support the lazy relations in jsp also.

**Update:** One thing I noticed is that you have a applicationContext.xml which is imported in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file, it will be better to not import applicationContext.xml in dispatcher-servlet.xml, instead load it using a ContextLoaderListener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then load up the rest of your dispatcher-servlet.xml normally. The reason I am saying this is only by this route does the `root application context` get registered as a singleton and available for the hibernate `sessionFactory` to be detected by the OSIV filter. Can you please try this also and see how it goes

Comment: No luck there either. Edited the original post to show what I attempted to do.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you have a common dispatcher-servlet.xml with the root context and the servlet specific context, can you please separate it out the way I have put in the update.

Comment: See the update. I had neglected to put that up when I extracted the parts of the web.xml. I've tried both with and without the <import> statement.

Comment: Can you enable trace/debug level and see if anything gets printed there. Also, can you show where you are expecting the relation to be expanded out.

Comment: "... an interceptor may not work, as interceptors complete their handling before the view is rendered, in this specific case before the jsp is rendered by the container the hibernate session would have been closed."


This is incorrect - the OSIV interceptor completes after the JSP is rendered and the Hibernate Session is open and available during JSP rendering. Better info on interceptor v filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753824/which-one-to-use-opensessioninviewinterceptor-or-opensessioninviewfilter