# OpenSessionInView working but not providing its session for @Transactional

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x, session-per-request

I am trying to use Spring MVC 3 and Hibernate 4.1 to get declarative transaction management, providing an open session for the entire length of the request.  I only have one "manager" layer for data access, which directly uses the session.  This is annotated with @Transactional, and the session closes upon exiting this layer and I get a lazy load exception in the controller.

So I added the OpenSessionInViewFilter filter, and the logs state that this filter is correctly configured and they also show this filter opening a session.  Unfortunately, my manager layer opens and closes its own session anyway, just as before, and I get the same lazy load exception in the controller.

Edit: noted that in my log, I get the filter session open, HibernateTransactionManager session open, HibernateTransactionManager session closed, lazy load exception, then filter session closed.  So I know that there is an open session somewhere during the lazy load exception, but the object was loaded in a transaction associated with the other, closed session.

I thought that removing @Transactional from the manager class would remove session management from that layer and let the filter do its job, but then the sessionFactory().getCurrentSession() simply gets a closed session; it doesn't have access to the filter's provided open session.

How can I get access to the OpenSessionInViewFilter's clearly open session?

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<beans ..

<context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="userManager" class="springapp.service.SimpleUserManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInView</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInView</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

hibernate-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ..
  ">

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/hibernate.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="managerTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="databeans" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

manager.java

```
@Service("userManager")
@Transactional
public class SimpleUserManager implements UserManager {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
..
```

controller.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
..
```

and my exception, which occurs in the controller, on the first property read of an object loaded in the manager class and passed to that controller:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

I've been researching this for hours.. all I can find is a mix of solutions using hibernate 3 and grainy explanations on hibernate 4 session/transaction theory without examples.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: FIXED!

Found this:

[Spring MVC OpenSessionInViewInterceptor Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904427/spring-mvc-opensessioninviewinterceptor-not-working)

which unfortunately has not helped the OP there, but it helped me.  Notably, this:

"it will be better to not import applicationContext.xml in dispatcher-servlet.xml, instead load it using a ContextLoaderListener"

which, applied to my configuration, is exactly everything I have posted above, but instead of

```
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

in my springapp-servlet.xml, I modified my ContextLoaderListener to:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/hibernate-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and that was all it took for

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

to return to me the OSIV-created session.  And, in fact, the second session that was being created is no longer, as I found these lovely little log lines:

```
2012-10-04 14:43:48,743 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2012-10-04 14:43:48,743 TRACE http-8080-1 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder@4146c5c0] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@12542011] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2012-10-04 14:43:48,743 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
2012-10-04 14:43:48,743 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [springapp.service.SimpleUserManager.find]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
```

which show that, outside of my @Transactional service layer, the OSIV-created session was alive and well, and a new transaction was simply started for it.

Hope this helps someone else.  I don't even want to think about how many hours I spent working on it.

Comment: Do you have a context:component-scan in the hibernate-context.xml?

Comment: Never mind, I missed the import in springapp-servlet.xml.

Comment: What package is SimpleUserManager in?

Comment: springapp.service.. implementing UserManager interface in the same package

Comment: You gave me an idea there, and I made the component-scan package simply 'springapp' to include both the service and web layers.  Same problem, though.  Also, the service layer does have a SessionFactory object, so regardless of it not being explicitly stated as a component-scan package, this @Autowired field is getting set.

Comment: FIXED: I'm a noob at SOF, so I can't answer my own question for another couple hours, but here's the rub:  I was doing an 'import resource' to get my hibernate-context.xml into the mix.  I removed that and expanded my contextConfigLocation in web.xml to include both hibernate-context.xml and springapp-servlet.xml.  Everything else is the same, and it works.